# Prevent text wrapper to span the entire width of its parent after text overflow to the next line

Tags: html, css

In responsive design, when I shrink the width, the text overflows to the next line and the text wrapper now takes the entire width of its parent.
Is there a way to prevent that? So it looks like the red container?

I could add padding on the container (and I will, like 1em) but thats still not what I want as it would make the text wrapper always be the same width (after overflow). I would rather have these text wrappers to have width based on its content.

Here is the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/derive/n2qk03wt/8/

Here is the testing code:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30%; 
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 20%;
  backgroud-color: #064f7f;
}

span {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
<span>some text here</span>
</div>

<div class="blue">
<span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below-attached css code.

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%; 
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 30%;
  background: blue;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 98%;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Edited: you need to set margin to `span` check updated snippet:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 20%;
  background: blue;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, but I dont want the spans to have the same width. Like I described, I would like to have the spans have width based on its content. If thats possible.